# how to make write.table to start writing from a new blank row always

Tags: r, shiny, write.table

I am using this in a shiny app

```
df = data.frame(doLogin()$Account,doLogin()$LoginTime)
write.table(df,file='collect_data/LoginUserData.csv', append=T, sep=',', col.names=F,   row.names=F)
```

After I restart the app, the text is overlapping with the previous line. I want write.table to find a new blank row and start writing from that new row.

Comment: Which OS do you use? Check the `write.table` option `eol` for details.

Comment: @xb. my local machine is Mac OS X and server is Red Hat Linux.

Comment: @xb. I tried using `eol='\r\n'`, it still over-writes on the previous row, hence overlapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could start by writing a line-end. Seems like the previous write operation was not getting completed properly:

```
df = data.frame(doLogin()$Account,doLogin()$LoginTime)
cat("\n", file='collect_data/LoginUserData.csv', append=TRUE)
write.table(df,file='collect_data/LoginUserData.csv', append=TRUE, sep=',', col.names=F,   row.names=F)
```